# Why is the lowest-ID row always returned when also returning a MAX value for a column?

Tags: mysql

Consider these two queries:

```
SELECT *, MAX(age) AS maxAge FROM someTable ORDER BY age ASC;
SELECT *, 'dummyC' AS dummyC FROM someTable ORDER BY age ASC;
```

The former query returns all rows and all columns of the table, plus an additional dummy column. The later query returns only a single row, that row which has the lowest primary key. Why is that, and how can I work around it? Tested in MySQL 5.1 on some old but stable Debian server.

Comment: Don't you have 'former' and 'latter' reversed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [MySQL extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

The value you get is indeterminate. You will often get the first row that was inserted into the table, but this is not guaranteed.

If you want the corresponding values from the row containing the highest age then it is better to use a combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Supposing that I were to need the values from the row containing the lowest age but also need the value of the highest age, how would I get that information is a single query? [I ask that as a separate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982629/how-to-query-row-with-lowest-value-and-also-to-know-the-value-of-the-highest-va).

Answer (score 2):

The first query has an aggregate function (`MAX`), but no `GROUP BY`, which means it aggregates (collects and combines values) over the entire result set and returns it as one row. Most SQL dialects do not allow for non-aggregated columns to appear in such a query, but MySQL specifically allows it. However, those non-aggregate columns are filled with values from the first row MySQL encounters, which may be any row. If you have never deleted from the table in question, MySQL usually finds the lowest-ID row first, because it scans the table in the same order as it is stored on disk (at least when a full table scan is required). If you were to run a bunch of `DELETE` and subsequent `INSERT` statements on your table, you'd get other rows on at least some queries. In short, don't count on getting any particular row.

The second query lacks the aggregate function, and hence it doesn't perform any implicit grouping - you simply get the full result set.

Answer (score 1):

In first query, * are [hidden columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Quoting MySQL documentation:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group