# How to query row with lowest value, and also to know the value of the highest value?

Tags: mysql

Consider these two queries:

```
SELECT *, 'b'    AS b    FROM someTable ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1;
SELECT *, MAX(a) AS maxA FROM someTable ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1;
```

The former query returns the row with the lowest value of `a`, as expected. The latter query returns the first row stored on disk (usually the row with the lowest value for primary key). **How can I work around this?** My intention is to get the full row of the column with the lowest `a` value (if there is more than one I only need one, it does not matter which), and additionally I do need the value of the highest age. In a perfect world I would run two queries, but due to the way that objects are serialised in this application I cannot do that without refactoring a lot of code that isn't mine. I actually don't mind if the MySQL engine itself must query twice, the important bit is that the output be returned in a single row. I cannot write a stored procedure for this query, unfortunately. And yes, the `*` operator is important, I cannot list the needed fields. And there are too many row to return them all!

Note that this question is superficially similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977850/why-is-the-lowest-id-row-always-returned-when-also-returning-a-max-value-for-a-c), however the question asked there was ill-formed and ambiguous, therefore all the answers addressed the issue that was not my intention (however useful, I did learn much and I'm happy that it turned out that way). This question asks the intended question more clearly and so should attract different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just run this:

```
SELECT MIN(a) as minA, MAX(a) AS maxA FROM someTable
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't know window functions. So if you really want to select `*` along with min/max values, I guess you'll have to resort to a JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM someTable ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1
) t1
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(a) as minA, MAX(a) AS maxA FROM someTable
) t2
```

Or to a subselect, as given in [Imre L's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982737/521799)

Comment: Thanks, but I do need all the columns of the row with the lowest value for `a`. I'll experiment a bit with the JOIN.

Comment: @dotancohen: Then the second query should give you those results

Comment: Interesting edit. I have never heard of a [CROSS JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) before. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this answer, despite the more concise answer below, for its versatility in future applications. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen: Thanks for the accept :) `CROSS JOIN` more explicitly communicates the intent of actually wanting to perform a cross join / cartesian product. With the comma-separated list of table-expressions in the `FROM` clause, cross joins might easily look like a bug / mistake. This goes in the same direction as preferring `A [INNER] JOIN B ON A.X = B.Y` over `FROM A, B WHERE A.X = B.Y`

Comment: Yes, I usually do explicitly mention INNER JOIN, though I rarely venture in other SQL dialects.

Answer (score 2):

use a subquery in select part:

```
SELECT *, 'b' AS b,
       (SELECT MAX(a) FROM someTable) AS maxA
  FROM someTable ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hmm, yes. That's more concise than my joining, actually.

Comment: Thank you. Though the most concise answer, I am accepting the more verbose answer for its versatility. This is probably what I'll use in this particular production app, though.